# Why does tufte-book turn beta into "fi"

Tags: bold, greek, tufte

When using the `\mathbf` command instead of `\boldsymbol`, greek symbols are not always made bold. However, when using the `tufte-book` document class, the beta symbol is changed into **fi**. What is **fi** and why does this happen?

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}

\[\beta\]
\[\mathbf{\beta}\]

\end{document}
```

Yields:
[image]

`\boldsymbol` does appear to work correctly, but where does this unrelated **fi** come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an oddity of the `mathpazo` font package.  For greek letters (OML encoding) you have to use `\mathbold`, because `\mathbf` switches to OT1 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}

\[b\beta\]
\[\mathbf{b\beta}\]
\[\mathbold{b\beta}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what about just using the `bm` package? Easier to type